# Why SpellChecker (C#) incorrectly defines words?

Tags: c#

I need to determine the correct spelling specific word from List. If word is wrong I write in in file. I used class SpellChecker, this is my code:

```
public class SpellChecker : IDisposable
{
    System.Type TWord = null; object com_app = null;

    private static SpellChecker Checker = new SpellChecker();
    private SpellChecker()
    {
        try
        {
            TWord = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
            com_app = Activator.CreateInstance(TWord);
        }
        catch { com_app = null; }
    }

    public static SpellChecker GetChecker() { return Checker; }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (com_app != null)
        {
            object[] arg = { null, null, null };
            TWord.InvokeMember("Quit", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                null, com_app, arg);
            com_app = null;
        }
    }
    public bool CheckWord(string word)
    {
        object[] arg = { word };
        return (bool)TWord.InvokeMember("CheckSpelling",
            BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, com_app, arg);
    }
}
```

But on the same word it working on different, if I setter List (with word) or just one word. 
In the process debug I see, that CheckWord give me true in one case, and false in another case. But it is one word, I sure.

```
var allWord = GetWords(xdoc);
            foreach (var word in allWord)
            {
                if (!spellChecker.CheckWord(word))
                {
                    result.WriteLine(word);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized. In some cases CheckWord give me wrong answer. For example, I need check russian and english word. If I give List list = List(){"GSM\MPG4\LTE", "Привет"}, then on first word in list it call me true, but second word will be false.